# GraphQL.js Node/Express: How to pass object as GraphQL query argument

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

My goal is to be able to pass an object as an argument in a GraphQL query.

Goal:

```
{
    accounts (filter: 
      {"fieldName": "id",
      "fieldValues":["123"],
      "filterType":"in"}){
        id
      }
 }
```

**Error:**

```
"message": "filterType fields must be an object with field names as keys or a function which returns such an object."
```

I've tried a few different approaches but this seems to be the closest to the potential solution.

**Schema:**

```
const filterType = new GraphQLObjectType ({
  name: 'filterType',
  fields: {
    fieldName: { type: GraphQLString },
    fieldValues: { type: GraphQLString },
    filterType: { type: GraphQLString },
  }
})

const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => ({
    accounts: {
      type: new GraphQLList(accountType),
      args: {
        filter: { type: new GraphQLInputObjectType(filterType) },
      },
      resolve: (root, args, { loaders }) => loaders.account.load(args),
    },

  }),
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I have found the solution here. 
https://github.com/mugli/learning-graphql/blob/master/7.%20Deep%20Dive%20into%20GraphQL%20Type%20System.md#graphqlinputobjecttype

**Schema:**

```
const filterType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'filterType',
  fields: {
    fieldName: { type: GraphQLString },
    fieldValues: { type: GraphQLString },
    filterType: { type: GraphQLString },
  }
})

const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => ({
    accounts: {
      type: new GraphQLList(accountType),
      args: {
        filter: { type: filterType },
      },
      resolve: (root, args, { loaders }) => {
        return loaders.account.load(args)},
    },
  }),
});
```

Problem was in the query, I had the both the keys and values as strings in the object argument.

**Correct Query:**

```
{
  accounts(filter: {fieldName: "id", fieldValues: "123", filterType: "in"}) {
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: Creating `GraphQLInputObjectType` and using it in such a way as you do in your query does not make any sense - you could simply define those fields in `args` instead creating new input type...

Comment: @piotrbienias args uses `GraphQLInputObjectType`. Using like that doesn't make any sense, but why? can't this be considered as a cleaner way, we have to define the field and type even though in args

Answer (score 3):

You don't define filterType as an object type then wrap it in an input type, you literally create it as an input type:

```
const filterType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'filterType',
  fields: {
    fieldName: { type: GraphQLString },
    fieldValues: { type: GraphQLString },
    filterType: { type: GraphQLString },
  }
})

const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => ({
    accounts: {
      type: new GraphQLList(accountType),
      args: {
        filter: { type: filterType },
      },
      resolve: (root, args, { loaders }) => loaders.account.load(args),
    },
  }),
});
```

You'll also want to declare its type at query time, as illustrated in @piotrbienias's answer.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for the input. I tried this solution and I receive the same error as before.  "Syntax Error GraphQL request (3:8) Expected Name, found String"